# Negation of universally quantified formula

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

The truth is that I do not know how to negate a logical proposition, for example the following:

$$(\forall x \in \mathbb R) (x^2 > x)$$

I do not want to determine its truth value since I know it is false. I want to negate the affirmation. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: $$(\exists x \in \mathbb R) (x^2 \leq x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have that:

$$\neg (\forall x) \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x) \neg \phi(x)$$

Applied to your formula:

$$\neg (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) (x^2 >x) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$(\exists x \in \mathbb{R}) \neg (x^2 > x)$$

but of course the claim $\neg (x^2 > x)$ is equivalent to the claim $x^2 \le x$, and so we get:

$$(\exists x \in \mathbb{R}) (x^2 \le x)$$